# intel xdk connecting mySQL database to application

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mobile, intel-xdk

i have been using intel XDK to create mobile applications recently. For this certain application, the user will register an account (username, password, confirm password) and then use their registration details to log into the application. i have decided to use mySQL to create a database to connect it to the application although i have no idea where to start. Can anyone advise me on this? Thank-you.

Comment: you say you have experience in creating mobile applications. So, what have you done so far and where exactly is your issue? Do you not know how to create the database, setup the database server, use it with php/js/your framework?

Comment: i have installed and setup my database with mySQL. i want to know how i can connect my application on intel XDK to mySQL database? has anyone came across any step by step guides online?

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect your html codes to a PHP script in a server by AJAX. You may use JSON to transfer data from PHP in server side to JS in the client side.

This seems to be a useful guide: http://qnimate.com/create-a-intel-xdk-app-with-php-and-mysql-backend/

There might be other nice guides. I googled "connect xdk to mysql", maybe this helps you.